# How to get text value from a unique div with same class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have five of following div s

```
<div class="timeline-axis-text timeline-axis-text-minor" style="position: absolute; left: -12px; top: 20px;">Text1</div>
<div class="timeline-axis-text timeline-axis-text-minor" style="position: absolute; left: -20px; top: 20px;">Text2</div>
<div class="timeline-axis-text timeline-axis-text-minor" style="position: absolute; left: -40px; top: 20px;">Text3</div>
<div class="timeline-axis-text timeline-axis-text-minor" style="position: absolute; left: -60px; top: 20px;">Text4</div>
<div class="timeline-axis-text timeline-axis-text-minor" style="position: absolute; left: -80px; top: 20px;">Text5</div>
```

I tried `$('.timeline-axis-text-minor').text()` and it prints out `"Text1Text2Text3Text4Text5"`, but I want to use `$('.timeline-axis-text-minor').each()` for iterating through these five elements and get the unique text values separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$('.timeline-axis-text-minor').each(function(){
  alert($(this).text());
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

[.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
var arr = $('.timeline-axis-text-minor').map(function(){ //get array of all the texts
   return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/G93CT/1)</kbd>

---

To get unique array after above code use

[jQuery.unique(array)](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/)

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/G93CT/2)</kbd>

```
arr= $.unique(arr);
```

---

[Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

to get Unique array

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/G93CT/)</kbd>

```
var text = []; //empty array
$('.timeline-axis-text-minor').each(function () {
    var val = $(this).text();
    if (text.indexOf(val) === -1) text.push(val); //if it not in the array than add it to array
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
$('.timeline-axis-text-minor').each(function(){
var uniqueText = $(this).text();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.timeline-axis-text-minor').map(function(){return $(this).text(); }).get().join("$");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var arr = []
$('.timeline-axis-text-minor').each(function () {
    arr.push($(this).text());
});
console.log(arr)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mVSPR/59/)

OR

If you want to get seperate

```
$('.timeline-axis-text-minor:eq(0)').text() //Return Text 1
```